# Automatically test for backwards compatibility

Tags: python, pytest

I'm developing a python package that writes / reads configuration files and I want to include some checks for backwards compatibility if I change the syntax of these configuration files.

My current idea is to checkout old versions of my package, create the configuration files for most scenarios, add them statically to my test suite and run pytest with the newest version to see if something breaks.

Ideally, I would prefer to split my tests into two parts

1. Create the config files with a selected revision of my package,
2. Use the newest revision of my package to read the files and assert some values,

but I don't really know how this could work.

What would be the best way to do such tests?

Comment: Add _new_ tests when changing the config format, rather than changing the old ones. You already have a test for backwards compatibility, because you already have a test for the old version. Over time you'll build up `v1-config-example.ext`, `v2-config-example.ext`, ... and a suite of tests that ensures the current implementation can deal with all of them (until you explicitly decide to deprecate a given vX and delete the associated tests).

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow your concept, but I agree with @jonrsharpe, you want to just accumulate tests in the current branch and don't bother automating checking out old versions of things.

Comment: Thanks, I have the issue in some parts of my tests that I test the functionality and creating the config files within that test with the newest version, but adding a unit test with both syntax is certainly the best way to go. Thanks for your time.